# Why is my Next.js Error reporting is so vague? This is making debugging so much more difficult

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

How do I make the error reporting for `Next.js` more elaborate?

This is how my `Next.js` error reporting on `localhost` looks like:

[image]

Sometimes even the highlighted line of code causing the error is **WRONG!**

Here is an example of the **WRONG** error reporting:

[image]

The **Error Message** is saying `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'find')` but the highlighted line has **NOTHING** TO DO with the **ERROR**!

This is the `Next.js` error reporting for `CodeSandbox`:

[image]

Unlike the first screenshot, it actually shows exactly which line of code is causing the error!

Comment: Please use errors?.country instead errors.country and please make sure you have import the reactDom module

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply, is the error reporting in my first screenshot actually normal? it seems pretty vague

Comment: Hi! Please post code, error messages, markup, data structures, and other textual information **as text**, not just as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: Hi, I have updated the question with a screenshot of the issue I am referring to, in the screenshot the ERROR MESSAGE and the HIGHLIGHTED LINE OF CODE is TOTALLY WRONG